# C# sqlite Unable to load sqlite3.dll

Tags: c#, sqlite, nuget

I have used nuget to install `sqlite-net` and `System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)`. I have rebuilt and I have restarted and I still get the following error: `Unable to load DLL 'sqlite3': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`. This is the line that triggers it:

```
db = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=C:\\Users\\xxxxxxx\\Desktop\\mydb.sqlite;Version=3;");
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't this just work?

Comment: Does that DLL file exist in your EXE directory?

Comment: There is not a sqlite3.dll but there is a System.Data.SQLite.dll.

Comment: Do I just rename it or something?

Comment: It's really a bad idea to hardcode a path to the database like this. Can you verify your project actually references correct libraries?

Comment: Download a precompiled binary package matching your architecture here https://www.sqlite.org/download.html and place the .dll into the bin\Debug or bin\Release folder. I think it could probably be an architecture mismatch between x86 and x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be an architecture mismatch between your application and the sqlite driver.

Download a precompiled binary package matching your architecture here  http://sqlite.org/download.html and place the .dll into the bin\Debug or bin\Release folder. I think it could probably be an architecture mismatch between x86 and x64.

From documentation you can see the needed deployment structure:

```
<bin>\App.exe (optional, managed-only application executable assembly)
<bin>\App.dll (optional, managed-only application library assembly)
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly)
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only LINQ assembly)
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll (optional, managed-only EF6 assembly)
<bin>\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly)
<bin>\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have installed two different ways to talk to SQLite from C# that are not entirely compatible: the thin sqlite-net wrapper around the native "sqlite3.dll" assembly, and the "System.Data.SQLite" full-featured .NET data provider for SQLite.

sqlite-net just adds some source files to your project (SQLite.cs and SQLiteAsync.cs). Inside these, you'll see lots of `extern` declarations like this:

```
[DllImport("sqlite3" , EntryPoint = "sqlite3_open_v2", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern Result Open ([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string filename, out IntPtr db, int flags, IntPtr zvfs);
```

sqlite-net assumes there is a file called "sqlite3.dll" in your output directory. Installing the `System.Data.SQLite` package does not give you this file, although the file "System.Data.SQLite.dll" is actually a mixed assembly that is compatible with "sqlite3.dll".

So you have two options:

1. Download the sqlite3.dll native library from http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
2. Find all the references in the sqlite-net source files that are now part of your project, and change them from

   ```
   [DllImport("sqlite3", ...
   ```

   to

   ```
   [DllImport("System.Data.SQLite.dll", ...
   ```

It's probably a good idea to pick one of the two approaches (sqlite-net or System.Data.SQLite) and uninstall the other package (both have pros and cons).

Comment: Correct answer over here, don't know why this got downvoted